# How can I specify a Kotlin function parameter with generic type in a constructor?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I want to pass a function that takes a T and returns a T, where T is the same type, to a constructor

So something like

```
class Foo(
    val f: (T) -> T
)
```

The thing is that the T can't be a generic type of the class - think passing an identity function - it will be used inside the class in different contexts

```
   val s: String = f("a string")
   val i: Int = f(42)
```

Is there any way to specify the type of f?

Comment: I should say - if anyone can think of a better title, please let me know!

Comment: Passing a generic type to the constructor of non-generic class is not possible, what is your use case? However, you still able add a generic function to the class, but you can't pass it to the constructor since the class is not generic, is that what you mean?

Comment: Well actually its a block to set up a transaction, but I figure that identity is simpler and equivalent

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the raw function type, I can define an interface:

```
interface ID {
    operator fun <R> invoke(r: R): R
}
```

then

```
class Foo(
    val f: Identity
)
```

inside the class

```
   val s = f("a string")
   val i = f(42)
```

I can create an id with

```
val id = object: ID {
    override fun <R> invoke(r: R): R = r
}
```

and instantiate Foo with it

```
val aFoo = Foo(id)
```